# your preferences cannot be read

Tags: windows, google-chrome

I have a problem every time I open the chrome.
I'm getting the error message:

```
Your preferences cannot be read.

Some features may be unavailable and changes to preferences won't be saved.
```

So, I have to sign in at chrome every fresh start.

I have search the web and the solution to reinstall chrome doesn't work for me. I find that the problem is a missing folder but I don't know who.

My operating system is Windows 8. Any help to overcome with my problem is more than appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

1. Exit Google Chrome completely.
2. Enter the keyboard shortcut Windows key+E to open Windows Explorer.
   In the Windows Explorer window that appears enter the following in the address bar:
   %LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data\
3. Locate the folder called "Default" in the directory window that opens and rename it as "Backup default."
4. Try opening Google Chrome again. A new "Default" folder is automatically created as you start using the browser.

Comment: Welcome to the stackoverflow community and thank you for the good answer! It seems to work.

Comment: This solution was not enough for me, I had to delete (or backup) the whole parent folder, Chrome. After that I could solve this error message.

Answer (score 0):

fix, error: preference files cannot read."

1. go to control panel
2. programs
3. uninstall
4. click on program getting error.
5. click repair

this fixed my problem.

Answer (score -2):

this problem can be solved easily..  once you have setup everything after the error message i.e bookmarks and sync, Run CHROME IN "ADMINISTRATOR MODE" every time you want to open chrome..that solves the issue..

Comment: Thx for the answer but the problem has solved and the most unsecure thing you may do is to run a web browser as administrator!